# Problem with subfig and pgfplots' graphs

Tags: pgfplots, subfloats

I have a problem with the `subfig`environment. My two graphs created with `pgfplots` are too large to stay together. How can I fix that?

```
% Graphique
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[]{$\tau = \SI{0.1}{\second}$}
    {\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title={Trajectoire de la balle dans le plan $x$-$z$}, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$z$},%
    legend cell align=left]

        \addplot[red,thick,each nth point={10}]
            table[x index=1,y index=3] {Data/magnus_nog_not_dt0.1s.dat};

        \legend{}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}} \quad

\subfloat[]{$\tau = \SI{0.001}{\second}$}
    {\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title={Trajectoire de la balle dans le plan $x$-$z$}, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$z$},%
    legend cell align=left]

        \addplot[red,thick,each nth point={10}]
            table[x index=1,y index=3] {Data/magnus_nog_not_dt0.001s.dat};

        \legend{}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}}

    \caption[]{}\label{g:nognot}
\end{figure}
% Graphique
```

Ps: I didn't provide a MWE because you need files to compile my graphs.

Comment: If they don't fit, they don't so maybe make them smaller with `width=0.4\textwidth` ?

Comment: @percusse The graphs are small, so I don't want to make them even smaller. In addition, I want all my graphs look the same way... ;)

Comment: Yes but what do you expect from us then? The question is not answerable because there is not much else to do.

Comment: @percusse Maybe there is some configuration of `subfig` that permit to the environment to exceed \textwidth... No? There is anything to do?

Comment: @R.M. So you want the graphs side by side, no matter if they exceed the margins? If that's so, then perhaps my answer could be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments it seems that was is required is a method to have the two graphs in the same row, no matter if the margins are exceeded; one way to achieve this is using a `\makebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}
\centering
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{%
\subfloat[]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) grid (7,3);
  \end{tikzpicture}}\quad
\subfloat[]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (8,0) grid (15,3);
  \end{tikzpicture}}
}\\
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{%
\subfloat[]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) grid (7,3);
  \end{tikzpicture}}\quad
\subfloat[]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (8,0) grid (15,3);
  \end{tikzpicture}}
}
\caption[]{}
\label{g:nognot}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I need, thank you. The problem now is that it seems the \\ command is ignored: the 4 graphs are placed in a single line instead of two lines... How I can fix that?

Comment: @R.M. Sorry but how can we anticipate four graphs in two rows when you only mentioned two graphs in your question? Anyway, the idea is the same: you can use two `\makebox`es (one for each row); I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: @R.M. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry! I posted an old version of my code!

Comment: @R.M. No problem; just make sure to provide precise information in your questions ;-) Did my updated answer helped?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. The problem is that the graphs captions are not centered under the graph... I will provide a MWE that shows the problem in a while. Should I open a new question?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6045/discussion-between-gonzalo-medina-and-r-m)